# How can we configure and Send User properties mobile app data from Firebase to Google Analytics via GTM?

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager

We have implemented google analytics for firebase on our ios app. We are tracking some custom events and user properties in addition to the firebase defaults.

We need to send these events and user properties to google analytics for reporting purpose.

Below is how we are trying to set up the tags and variable for user properties.

Custom User Properties on Firebase
[image: Custom User Properties on Firebase]

Tag in GTM for user property Primary internal source
[image: Tag in GTM for user property Primary internal source]

Variable in GTM for user property Primary internal source
[image: Variable in GTM for user property Primary internal source]

Need advice on where we are going wrong as this setup is not pushing the data to GA.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem... I can't believe it is not be possible -for example- to use first_open_time (the most basic user property automatically collected by firebase) and sent it as a custom metric to GA!

Comment: Fyi, I posted this question https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/a6JYbxD2QA8 on the GTM forum.